# WebBrowser control does not display images

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, webbrowser-control

I've got this problem using the WebBrowser control of Visual Studio for a VB.NET app. I put the control, but when I browse,  images don't show correctly.

I took a random wiki page and this happened:

[image]

I use VS2008 and X64.

Comment: Is that for all web-sites? It maybe not existing picture on this random page.

Comment: when i visit this page using chrome, or ie i can see all the pictures